# to arrange the value in columns as per value in 1st column

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed, solaris

I have a file with following data

```
cat text.txt
281475473926267,46,47
281474985385546,310,311
281474984889537,248,249
281475473926267,16,17
281474985385546,20,28
281474984889537,112,68
```

The values in 1st column are duplicate at some places
i want o/p as given below

```
cat output.txt
281475473926267 16,17,46,47
281474985385546 20,28,310,311
281474984889537 68,112,248,249
```

It should print uniq values of column 1 and then space and then it should print respective values of other column in one line arranged in ascending order.

I tried below:

```
cat text.txt | perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++; END { while(my($x,$y) = each(%kv)) { print "$x ",join(",",keys %$y) }}'

281474984889537 112,248
281474985385546 310,20
281475473926267 46,16
```

here i am not able to print all the values in front of value in 1st column

for 281474984889537 it should print 68,112,248,249, but its printing only 112,248

also i am not sure how to arrange them in ascending order.

```
cat text.txt | perl -F, -lane ' $kv{$F[0]}{$F[1]}++; END { while(my($x,$y) = each(%kv)) { print "$x ",join(",",keys %$y) }}'

281474984889537 112,248
281474985385546 310,20
281475473926267 46,16
```

here i am not able to print all the values in front of value in 1st column

Comment: Are there always 3 columns?

Comment: yes. always 3 columns

Comment: it is possible that there can be more columns like 281475473926267,46,47,12,13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multi-step

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1,$2; print $1,$3}' file             | 
  sort -k1n -k2n                                        | 
  awk 'p!=$1{if(p) print p,a[p]; a[$1]=$2; p=$1; next} 
            {a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2} 
       END  {print p,a[p]}'                             | 
  sort -k2n

281475473926267 16,17,46,47
281474985385546 20,28,310,311
281474984889537 68,112,248,249
```

Comment: thanks. working to get the values in one row but not helping me to arrange in ascending order . please see my o/p---------------------------------------------------------------sort -t, -k2n snclabeltest.txt | awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1]=a[$1] sep[$1] $i; sep[$1]=FS}} END {for(k in a) print k, a[k]}'
281474984889537 112,68,248,249
281475473926267 16,17,46,47
281474985385546 20,28,310,311          ----------------------------------------------------------112,68,248,249 is not in ascending order (min to max)

Comment: yes, I noticed the same issue and updated the script.  Please test the new one.

Comment: awk -F, '{print $1,$2; print $1,$3}' snclabeltest.txt | sort -k1n -k2n | awk 'p!=$1{if(p) print p,a[p]; a[$1]=$2; p=$1; next} {a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2} END  {print p,a[p]}' | sort -k2n
281475473926267 16,17,46,47
281474985385546 20,28,310,311
281474984889537 68,112,248,249

Comment: @JeevanPatil if the same value appears for the same key on multiple input lines then it'll show up multiple times in the output. Is that your desired behavior? Add a line like `281475473926267,16,18` to your posted sample input and then look at the script output to see what I mean.

Comment: yes.. i got your point. Actually for input file, there should not be any duplicate value in 2nd column, as of now i just came across some garbage duplicate values and and i neglected them . So as of now above command look perfect.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        keyVals[$1][$i]
    }
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (key in keyVals) {
        vals = ""
        for (val in keyVals[key]) {
            vals = (vals == "" ? "" : vals ",") val
        }
        print key, vals
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
281474984889537 68,112,248,249
281474985385546 20,28,310,311
281475473926267 16,17,46,47
```

The above will work no matter how many fields you have on each line and it will remove duplicate values when they occur on multiple lines for the same key value.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'H;x;s/((\n[^\n,]*),[^\n]*)(.*)\2([^\n]*)\n?/\1\4\3/;x;$!d;x;s/.//;:b;h;s/\n.*//;s/[^,]*,//;s/,/\n/g;s/.*/echo "&"|sort -n|paste -sd,/e;G;s/^([^\n]*)\n([^\n,]*),[^\n]*/\2 \1/;P;:c;tc;s/[^\n]*\n//;tb;d' file
```

The script works in two parts. In the first part of the processing the lines of the file are held in memory and reduced in size by appending values of the same key to a single key. At the end of file the second part of processing is enacted. Each line is broken into two, the appended values are sorted and re-appended to the key, printed and removed, until all the lines have been processed.

Answer (score 0):

To correct your Perl-oneliner, use this.

```
$ cat text.txt
281475473926267,46,47
281474985385546,310,311
281474984889537,248,249
281475473926267,16,17
281474985385546,20,28
281474984889537,112,68

$ cat text.txt | perl -F, -lanE ' @t1=@{$kv{$F[0]}}; push(@t1,@F[1..2]); $kv{$F[0]}=[@t1]; END { while(my($x,$y) = each(%kv)) { print "$x ",join(",",@{$y}) }}'
281474985385546 310,311,20,28
281475473926267 46,47,16,17
281474984889537 248,249,112,68

$
```

When you have more columns, a small change on the above one-liner from `1..2` to `1..$#F` will do the trick. Check this out

```
$ cat > text2.txt
281475473926267,46,47,49
281474985385546,310,311
281474984889537,248,249,311,677,213
281475473926267,16,17
281474985385546,20,28
281474984889537,112,68,54,78,324,67


$ cat text2.txt | perl -F, -lanE ' @t1=@{$kv{$F[0]}}; push(@t1,@F[1..$#F]); $kv{$F[0]}=[@t1]; END { while(my($x,$y) = each(%kv)) { print "$x ",join(",",@{$y}) }}'
281474984889537 248,249,311,677,213,112,68,54,78,324,67
281474985385546 310,311,20,28
281475473926267 46,47,49,16,17

$
```